# ZeroMQ's native libraries - can they be moved?

Tags: java, macos, zeromq

I have built the ZeroMQ native libraries and jar according to the instructions in http://blog.pmorelli.com/getting-zeromq-and-jzmq-running-on-mac-os-x

What I want to do now is to move those files inside my IntelliJ project. This does not seem to work at all. Is it even possible or are they required to stay in /usr/local/lib ?

Comment: Did you try overriding java.library.path and pointing it to your application folder(s)?

Comment: I guess I could try that with a relative path. I have not though. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The libraries can be moved to anywhere you want. Since you re on OSX, you need to set the `-Djava.library.path=/lib/local/lib` for your application (or where you move the libraries). I usually set the VM option as a default for the Run configurations.

Comment: It needs to work on both win and mac, and the win libs are in the project. I tried copying the generated files into the project, but it did not seem to work. Probably worth trying again since you say I should be able to. Is everything I need to move in the /usr/local/lib folder?

Comment: Yes, everything is in the /usr/local/lib folder (you need the libjzmq and the libzmq files). If you want it to work under windows, you just need to add the folder containing the dll's to your windows PATH environment variable.

Comment: It's already working for windows. That was just a dll, but for the mac loads of files and directories were created. I'll try again.

Comment: looks like a lot of the /usr/local/lib are relative links into /usr/local/Cellar/zeromq. Probably broke all that copying

Comment: They are "soft links". That would explain your issue copying.

Comment: Makes it a lot harder to move. Maybe I need to move/copy both folders into my project. Seems messy :)